# Python 3: Iterator that is NOT a generator?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I'm trying to understand the difference between iterator and generator. I read that "Every generator is an iterator, but not vice versa."

Could someone give an example of an object that IS an iterator, but IS NOT a generator?

I mean, if an object has method **next** (which is the definition of an iterator), we can also call it a generator, can't we?

UPD: for those who say that generator must have **yield** - not always. (i**2 for i in range(1,5)) doesn't have yield and is also a generator.

For those who say that iter([1,2,3]) is not a generator - why? Which definition of a generator it contradicts and where?

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do/231855#231855

Comment: "I mean, if an object has method next (which is the definition of an iterator), we can also call it a generator, can't we?" **No**. You can't. Generator objects are created by generator functions (functions that use `yield`) which are a specific language construct. Just because it has a `__next__` method **does not make it a generator**

Comment: Anyway, for an example of non-generator iterators, pretty much choose any iterator created from a built-in type. So, `list_iterator = iter([1,2,3])`, or `string_iterator = iter("abcde")`

Comment: Generator objects are created by generator functions (functions that use yield) - not always. (i**2 for i in range(1,5)) is also a generator, I guess.

"Anyway, for an example of non-generator iterators, pretty much choose any iterator created from a built-in type" - so, why iter([1,2,3]) is not a generator? Which definition of a generator it contradicts and where?

Comment: @Timur if you disassemble a generator expression, youlld find a generator function

Comment: As for `list_iterator`, try `import types; print(isinstance(list_iterator, types.GeneratorType))` generator is an actual *type* that implements the iterator protocol. And it isn't one because it **isn't created by a generator function**. Note, generators have *additional* methods, e.g. `.send()`.

Comment: So the difference is merely formal? Generator generates new objects that we don't know yet, whereas an iterator iterates over objects we already know (such a list).

Comment: **No**. I already explained it to you. A generator is a *specific type* created by generator functions. If you do `type(mygen)` it will give you generator . An iterator is any object with a `__next__` method. Generator objects are iterators, a specific *type of iterator*

Comment: @Timur - Prob. you can read this article - https://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Every generator is an iterator, but not vice versa."

I don't think that's necessarily true. The [Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) gives 3 entries that start with "generator".

### Generator

This is any function with a `yield` statement. A generator function is not an iterator, but it does return an iterator when you call it.

```
def getSquares(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i**2
```

### Generator iterator

This is the thing that gets returned by a generator function.

### Generator expression

This is just a comprehension inside parentheses.

```
(i**2 for i in range(10))
```

Generator expressions and the return values of generator functions both give `<class 'generator'>` when you call `type` on them. However, if you define your own class with a `__next__` method, its instances will, of course, have that class as their `type`.

Comment: "Generator" can refer to either a generator function or a generator iterator, depending on context. The glossary says "Usually refers to a generator function, but may refer to a generator iterator in some contexts.", but in my experience, the iterator usage is more common.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone give an example of an object that IS an iterator, but IS NOT a generator?

Generator in Python often means a function, but can also mean an iterator created by that function. So your question is better phrased as:

> Could someone give an example of an object that IS an iterator, but IS NOT a generator iterator?

Here it is:

```py
class MyIterator:

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n == 4:
            raise StopIteration
        n, self.n = self.n, self.n + 1
        return n


it = MyIterator()
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
```